# Why is the decorated function's name not used when an argument error occurs?

Tags: python

I understand the purpose of `functools.wraps` - to carry over attributes like `__doc__`, `__name__`, etc. But I'm struggling to explain why the below is happening. I have this decorator function in Python:

```
from functools import update_wrapper
class Environment:
    ...

def requires_environment(function: Callable) -> Callable:
    def wrapped_function(*args, environment, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(environment, Environment):
            raise TypeError("The environment keyword argument must be of type Environment.")
        kwargs["environment"] = environment
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    update_wrapper(wrapped_function, function)
    return wrapped_function
```

Then I decorate a function with it:

```
@requires_environment
def function_with_args(arg1, arg2, environment):
   pass
```

When I do not provide an `environment` keyword to my `function_with_args`, I expect that the error message should say `TypeError: function_with_args()`:

```
function_with_args(1, 2, Environment.PROD)
```

I get

```
TypeError: wrapped_function() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'environment'
```

Why is `wrapped_function` showing instead of `function_with_args`? If I print get rid of the syntactic sugar of the `@` decorator and print the function name, even after decoration, it is properly saying that the new wrapped function's name is `function_with_args`:

```
function_with_args = requires_environment(function_with_args)
print("After", function_with_args.__name__) # After function_with_args
function_with_args(1, 2, Environment.PROD)
```

Yet I still see my `wrapped_function` name in the `TypeError`. Why is this occuring?

Below is my complete reproducible example:

```
from time import perf_counter
from typing import Callable
from enum import Enum
from functools import update_wrapper

class Environment(Enum):
    PROD = "PROD"
    STAGING = "STAGING"
    DEV = "DEV"


def requires_environment(function: Callable) -> Callable:
    def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if "environment" not in kwargs:
            raise TypeError(f"{function.__name__}() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'environment'")

        if not isinstance(kwargs['environment'], Environment):
            raise TypeError("The environment keyword argument must be of type Environment.")

        return function(*args, **kwargs)

    update_wrapper(wrapped_function, function)

    return wrapped_function


@requires_environment
def function_with_args(arg1, arg2, environment):
    print(f"Inside function {function_with_args.__name__}")
    print(f"Docstrings: {function_with_args.__doc__}")

function_with_args(1, 2, Environment.PROD)
```

Comment: What's `update_wrapper`?

Comment: Yes, same question.  Please make a [mcve].

Comment: @DanielWalker `update_wrapper` is a function in the `functools` module of the standard library. It is used under the hood by `functools.wraps`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper

Comment: @MarkTolonen please accept my sincerest apologies for not including a standalone piece of code. Have added it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error message uses the code object's name, not the function object's name. Code objects can't be renamed; even after `functools.update_wrapper` sets the function's `__name__`, the function's code object's `co_name` is still `wrapped_function`. You can see this by examining `function_with_args.__code__.co_name`.

This behavior is [scheduled to change](https://bugs.python.org/issue40679) in Python 3.10 to use the function's `__qualname__`, to better disambiguate identically-named methods of different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try:

When you pass you function argument are below

```
function_with_args(1, 2, Environment.PROD)
```

the wrapper function is taking all the inputs are as args only!

```
def wrapped_function(*args, environment, **kwargs):
```

As you can see, the wrapper function is unpacking all input arguments based on a key-value argument `environment`. All args before this key becomes part of `*args` and all args after this becomes `*kwargs`

Wrapper function looks up for `environment=<something>`! So you always have to pass like

```
function_with_args(1, 2, environment=Environment.PROD)
```

Suggestion: I would try to do like this

```py
def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs): # this is good! dont change it here
    ...
    if `environment` in locals(): # checking if environment key is passed/defined as args
        print(environment) # do you stuff here
```